# display new UIview when row is selected from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableView which has 3 rows. the first row calls a phone number when pressed, which is working fine.

I have two other UIViewControllers which I would like to be displayed when the respective row is selected in the UITableView.

Below is my didSelectRow method.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1800333000"]];
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I've set up my switch expression. Im trying to figure out how to call the other two UIViews.

Could someone please provide the code required to display these views?

Comment: What dou you mean with "UIViewControllers which you like to be displayed"? Should they create new cells in the UITableView or should they open as totally new ViewControllers, modally or not?

Comment: my apologies - i have 2 UIViews in storyboard which i want to access depending on what row is selected. normally i would just use a segue in storyboard, but i can't do that with UITableview.

Comment: You can use segues to do this -- you just need to connect them directly from the controller (not the cell), and decide which one to call based on which row is chosen.

Comment: I didn't realise this was possible - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear about what exactly you are doing but I think what you need is to make a segue and specifically a segue from a UITableViewCell.

First thing to do is control-click and drag a connection from your UITableView cell to the other view in the storyboard. This should create a line between the table view cell and the next view with a little circle. Click on that circle to set and edit the segue properties in the properties inspector. Then in the UITableViewController class you need to have a prepare for segue method. Here is some example code that I've written, its got an extra if statement in there because I actually had 2 UITableViews - one from the UITableViewController and one from the searchbarviewcontroller (which was within the UITableViewController).

```
// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {


    NSIndexPath * SBidxPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    NSIndexPath * TBidxPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSIndexPath * idxPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
    if (!SBidxPath) {
        idxPath = TBidxPath;
    }
    else{
        idxPath = SBidxPath;
    }


        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:CELL_PUSH_SEGUE_ID]) {
            if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[YTViewController class]]) {
                [self prepareYTViewController:segue.destinationViewController withDictionaryEntry:[self.dictionaryEntries objectAtIndex:idxPath.row]];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The other thing is that you also need to look into what a NSIndexPath is. Typically the property that you use from that structure is the .row property.

Comment: But won't this only link to one UIView, regardless of what row is selected?

Comment: No, you can link to multiple views, depending on what the segue identifier is (which is a variable that you set). So based on what row gets selected, you can choose the appropriate segue.